# How to fill up the missing values in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, predict

I have two data.tables in which I have some missing values. The non-missing values make a curve and the missing values should fit into this curve.

```
temp_dt_1 = structure(list(x = c(33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 50, 
51.5, 52.5, 53, 54, 55, 55.5, 56, 56.5, 57, 57.5, 58, 59, 59.5, 
60, 60.5, 61, 61.5, 62, 62.5, 63, 63.5, 64, 65, 66, 66.5, 67, 
67.5), y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.33, NA, NA, 1.6, NA, NA, 0.91, NA, 0.665, 
NA, 0.465, 0.39, 0.325, 0.265, 0.24, 0.135, 0.1, 0.095, NA, 0.105
)), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

> temp_dt_1 
       x     y
 1: 33.0    NA
 2: 34.0    NA
 3: 35.0    NA
 4: 36.0    NA
 5: 37.0    NA
 6: 38.0    NA
 7: 39.0    NA
 8: 40.0    NA
 9: 45.0    NA
10: 50.0    NA
11: 51.5    NA
12: 52.5    NA
13: 53.0    NA
14: 54.0    NA
15: 55.0    NA
16: 55.5    NA
17: 56.0    NA
18: 56.5 2.330
19: 57.0    NA
20: 57.5    NA
21: 58.0 1.600
22: 59.0    NA
23: 59.5    NA
24: 60.0 0.910
25: 60.5    NA
26: 61.0 0.665
27: 61.5    NA
28: 62.0 0.465
29: 62.5 0.390
30: 63.0 0.325
31: 63.5 0.265
32: 64.0 0.240
33: 65.0 0.135
34: 66.0 0.100
35: 66.5 0.095
36: 67.0    NA
37: 67.5 0.105
```

The second `data.table` has missing values on both sides (at start and end of `y`) -

```
temp_dt_2 = structure(list(x = c(25, 27.5, 30, 32.5, 35, 40, 43, 45, 47, 
50, 52.5, 55, 57.5, 60, 65, 85, 90), y = c(NA, NA, 1.1, NA, 
1.765, 2.64, 3.42, 3.975, NA, 5.625, 6.95, 7.825, 8.95, 10.375, 
13.725, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

In the plot below the black line shows the known points (which are present in data.table) and the red line is the approximate expected output for `temp_dt_1`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp_dt_1, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

I am looking for only `data.table` solution. I will really appreciate it if the code has good performance.

Comment: What is your expected output?  i.e. how do you want to fill the missing values

Comment: I have added the approximate output. The output should fall approximately on the red line in the graph above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `approxfun`, `splinefun`, `loess`, ... to fill up missing values.

```
res <- cbind(a = approxfun(temp_dt_1$x, temp_dt_1$y, rule=2)(temp_dt_1$x),
s = splinefun(temp_dt_1$x, temp_dt_1$y)(temp_dt_1$x), 
l = predict(loess(y ~ x, temp_dt_1, control = loess.control(surface = "direct")), temp_dt_1))

plot(temp_dt_1$x, temp_dt_1$y, ylim=range(res))
for(i in 1:3) lines(temp_dt_1$x, res[,i], col=i, lwd=2)
legend("topright", c("approxfun", "spline", "loess"), lty=1, lwd=2, col=1:3)
```

[image: Plot of interpolated points]

Answer (score 3):

One method is to fit a model with the available data and then predict the missing data.

Here I am using a second order polynomial to fit the data:

```
#filter original down to just the complete cases
df <- temp_dt_1[complete.cases(temp_dt_1),]

#model <-lm(I(log(y))~ x, data=df)
#fitting a 2 order pplynomial
model <-lm(y~ poly(x, degreee= 2, raw=TRUE), data=df)
summary(model)

#predicting new values using the original x values.
newy <- predict(model, temp_dt_1)

#plotting
plot(df$x, df$y, xlim = c(40, 70), ylim= c(0, 20))
lines(temp_dt_1$x, newy)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dave! This solution is very close to the expected output. I am testing it on other data tables.